# How do I make jenkins accept commands over xmpp?

Tags: xmpp, jenkins

I'm trying to get jenkins to accept commands over XMPP (Spark client) but all I get in reply is:

> (11:27) jenkins: bhumphreys you're not a buddy of me. I won't take any
>   commands from you!

I can't find a setting to apply - any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using on Jenkins, Jabber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be on the jenkin's roster. The easiest way to achieve that with no programming would be to log in as bhumphreys, add the jenkins jid as a contact, log in as jenkins accept, tada!

Comment: With Spark there doesn't seem to be that option - i logged into Spark as jenkins using another machine and had a conversation with myself but jenkins still refuses to listen :)

Comment: Spark is just a client no? Use some other client if you can't add contacts, but I doubt it's not possible. With two clients connected simultaneously, one as jenkins and one as bhumphreys they should be able to see each other and chat.

Comment: Yes we can - but then after i log out and let the build server login it still won't let me execute commands

Comment: Sorry then out of ideas. Worked fine for me.

Comment: After installing latest jenkins on another (new improved) server this is working. No idea what was done differently.